# J interpretation of infinities

Tags: j

I have some difficulties understanding how J interprets infinities, for example `(cos=.2&o.^:_)1` is 0.73908 and `((^&2)^:_) 2` is _,  but `((+&1)^:_) 0` hung my computer instead of answering _. How does the cosine and power examples work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form `v ^:_ y` will apply v to y until there is no change. In other words it can be used as a convergence test.

`((+&1)^:_) 0` NB. adds one each time that it executes... slowly reaches infinity

`((^&2)^:_) 2` NB. increases much quicker so gets to _ (infinity) quicker

`(cos=.2&o.^:_)1` NB. converges

In J for C programmers Henry Rich gives a good description of the uses of ^:_
http://www.jsoftware.com/help/jforc/loopless_code_iv_irregular_o.htm#_Toc191734389

Answer (score 3):

Your computer hangs because there are a lot (like **A LOT**) of steps until the last calculation reaches `_`.

If you keep the intermediate steps you can easily see how fast the cosine converges:

```
(2&o.^:(<_)) 1
1 0.540302 0.857553 0.65429 ...
#(2&o.^:(<_)) 1
77
```

In just 77 steps it reached a steady point.

Likewise, `^&2` increases very fast so it reaches its steady point (`_`) very soon:

```
((^&2)^:(<_)) 2
2 4 16 256 65536 4.29497e9 1.84467e19 3.40282e38 1.15792e77 1.34078e154 _
#((^&2)^:(<_)) 2
11
```

`(+&1)` on the other hand, is a very slowly increasing function. Starting from 0, you have to wait about 1e19 steps until it reaches a steady point; i.e. a number `x` that is tolerantly equal to `x+1`